# Memory leak using UseEffect,happens only once for some reason

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

i got an async call being made in a reducer outside the use effect,
when i switch to the home page from the app page i get a memory leak,
The Call is being made in a different file.
any suggestions on a fix?

The Call:

```
export const query = createAsyncThunk('loadToys', () =>
    axios.get(baseUrl)
   .then(ok => ok.data)
   .catch(err => err),
);
```

The App:

```
const toysFromDb = useSelector(CurrToys)
  const [localStateToys, setToys] = useState([])
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const mountedRef = useRef(true)


  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true;
    if (isSubscribed) {
      dispatch(query()).then(data => {
        setToys(toysFromDb)
      })
    }
    return () => isSubscribed = false
  }, [localStateToys])
```

Comment: use this const useMountEffect = (fun) => useEffect(fun, []) instead of useEffect, and it will send request only once..  => useMountEffect(() => {your logic here})

Comment: that's the only solution?

Comment: you should make some condition , when to stop making requests, if you doesn't add this condition if will be in infinite loop.  you can make const [isInitial, setIsInitial] = useState(true) , then if (isSubscribed && isInitial) {setIsInitial(false) and all logic below}

Comment: Why would you copy toys to local state if it's already written to redux store? I assume that toysFromDb and localStateToys are the same thing.

Comment: How Would i write it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Solved This:
all i needed to do was the following:

```
 const toysFromDb = useSelector(CurrToys);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    // call the action that will update the store
    dispatch(query());
  }, []);
```